# Anchored Pull Function Breaks at Low Framerate

Tags: mathematics, movement

To start, I'm not working with an engine and am looking for some help fixing the math behind the function I created.

Say we have `anchor`, `obj`, `speed`, `dt`, and `terminationDist` ; function `anchorPull` will theoretically pull `obj` towards `anchor` at a rate of `speed` pixels per second until the distance from `anchor` to `obj` is less than `terminationDist`. My implementation is as follows:

```
def anchorPull(anchor, obj, speed, dt, termDist = 10):

    if dist(anchor, obj) > termDist:
        deltaX1 = obj.x - anchor.x
        deltaY1 = obj.y - anchor.y

        theta = degrees(atan(deltaX1/deltaY1))

        deltaX2 = sin(theta) * speed * dt
        deltaY2 = cos(theta) * speed * dt

        obj.x += deltaX2
        obj.y += deltaY2
```

Visual Representation:
[image: Visual Representation]

The problem is, at low framerates (a high `dt`) `obj` wont go all the way to `anchor`:
[image]

`obj` will also stochastically move around when `anchor` isn't stationary.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: How about setting the position when stopped? The dt in the real world is infinitely small, and some situations cannot be simulated by the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to implement a MoveTowards function. Try something more like this:

```
def moveTowards(mover, target, maxStep):

    deltaX = target.x - mover.x
    deltaY = target.y - mover.y

    mag = deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY

    if mag < maxStep * maxStep:
        mover.x = target.x
        mover.y = target.y 
    else:
        scale = maxStep / sqrt(mag)
    
        mover.x += deltaX * scale
        mover.y += deltaY * scale
```

Or, to stop at a fixed distance away from the object, modify like so:

```
def moveTowardsOrbit(mover, target, maxStep, stopDistance):

    deltaX = target.x - mover.x
    deltaY = target.y - mover.y

    distance = sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY)

    unitScale = 1 / distance

    deltaX *= unitScale
    deltaY *= unitScale

    onCircleX = target.x - deltaX * stopDistance
    onCircleY = target.y - deltaY * stopDistance

    fromStop = distance - stopDistance

    if abs(fromStop) <= maxStep:
        mover.x = onCircle.x
        mover.y = onCircle.y 
    else:
        if fromStop < 0:
            deltaX *= -1
            deltaY *= -1
    
        mover.x += deltaX * maxStep
        mover.y += deltaY * maxStep
```

Call this with `moveTowards(obj, anchor, speed * dt, 10)`.

This version...

- Picks a point on the circle `stopDistance` away from the `anchor` and moves toward that - whether that takes it inward or outward along the line joining `obj` and `anchor`.
- Moves the object at most a distance of `maxStep` per invocation.
- When the destination is closer than `maxStep`, it snaps the object directly to the `stopDistance` circle, with no under- or over-shooting.
- Uses no trigonometric functions. It also handles all angles correctly, unlike the sample code (hint: you probably want `atan2` when trying to find an angle from two coordinates).

You should also consider [using a fixed timestep for your game simulation](https://www.gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/), so it's not subject to variation depending on the rendering framerate.

Comment: Thanks, these work great! One small modification to the moveTowardsOrbit function: `if abs(fromStop) <= speed:
  obj.x = onCircleX
  obj.y = onCircleY`

Comment: No, that is not the correct change to make.